# If ip address of a PC is dynamic is mac address static?

Tags: ip, mac-address, ip-address

I am trying a open a specific port on my PC with defining ip address, since my ip is dynamic I am wondering if it is possible to do it with defining mac address and send packets based on mac-address rather than ip-address?
Is mac address of a PC static or dynamic?

Comment: "_I am trying a open a specific port on my PC..._" Do you mean trying to forward a port on your router/firewall? Host (PC) configurations are off-topic here. If this is on you router/firewall, we need the full configuration (obfuscate any passwords or public addresses).

Answer (score 3):

The MAC address is pretty much static. It is integrated into the NIC hardware, but can often be changed by various methods. Each MAC address is usually globally unique but it needs to be only locally unique to work. The MAC address is used for the layer 2 network (the local segment, LAN, ...) that is connected by switches (or repeater hubs).

On top of that, a layer 3 network uses logical addresses (IPv4, IPv6) that are unique on a global level (unless they're private). Different layer 3 networks are connected by routers.

Since MAC addresses can only be used within their local segment, you can't use them for port forwarding or similar.

When your IP address is dynamic you can either pay your ISP for a static IP or use a dynamic DNS service that always points to your current IP.